# to insert element from one array to another when condition is true

Tags: java, arrays

I am using 2 arrays. From the first array is want to check which number is prime and if the number is prime then I want to insert that number into to second array and then I want to print the second array.

In this it only insert the first element of the first array whether it is prime or not but I want to insert only if it is prime.

```
import java.util.*;

class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] a1={9,5,7,3,4,6};
        int[] a2=new int[4];
        int index=0;
        boolean isprime=true;
        //to check for prime
        for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(a1[i]);
            for(int j=2;j<a1[i];j++)
            {
                if(a1[i]%j==0)
                {
                    isprime=false;
                    break;
                }
            } //to add into another array
            if(isprime)
                {
                    a2[index++]=a1[i];

                }
        }

        for(int k=0;k<a2.length;k++)
        {
            System.out.println(a2[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

5, 7, 3

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies with you flag isprime. It is set to true only once before any loop and it will be set to false forever when the algorithm will process first non-prime number. If you put *boolean isprime=true;* inside the first loop it works.

See bellow:

```
//to check for prime
for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
{
   boolean isprime=true;
   //rest of the program
}
```